# How to set object to null-value that can be boolean checked?

Tags: vba

I have a VBA function that returns a Dictionary, and then if there's an error in building the Dictionary, takes a certain action.  Like so:

```
Public Sub takeAction(s as string)

Dim dict as Dictionary
Set dict=makeADictionary(s)
If dictionaryIsOK(dict) Then
 doSomething
Else
 doSomethingElse
End If

End Sub
```

I'm having trouble making the `dictionaryIsOK` function, because if I try setting a Dictionary to `Nothing` as a way of indicating a null value, it seems that this value can't be checked for.  For example:

```
Sub testNothing()

Dim d As New Dictionary

Set d = Nothing
Debug.Print d Is Nothing

End Sub
```

This prints `false`, even though I set `d` to `Nothing`.  This appears to be true for all other object types as well.

So, what null value can I assign to an object, in this case a Dictionary, and what would be the boolean check for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim d As New Dictionary
```

In VBA/VB6, the above means "Declare variable `d` that magically always contains an instance of `Dictionary`. If I ever set the variable to `Nothing`, instantiate a new `Dictionary` for me next time I access the variable."

You want to remove `New`:

```
Dim d As Dictionary
```

And then you can check if the variable `Is Nothing` or not.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't know that about `Dim x as new y`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate correctly.  This works:

```
Dim d As Dictionary
Set d = New Dictionary
Set d = Nothing
Debug.Print d Is Nothing
```